# NetBeans 8.2 marks me syntax error with a symfony file

Tags: symfony, netbeans

```
/**
 * Gets the public 'factory_service' shared service.
 *
 * @return \Bar
 */
protected function getFactoryServiceService()
{
    return $this->services['factory_service'] = ($this->services['foo.baz'] ?? $this->getFoo_BazService())->getInstance();
}
```

[image: ERROR IN THE IMAGE]

Comment: Is your project configured as PHP7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest NetBeans Build. Update to NetBeans Build 201804200002 and it will work.

http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/